# CollectionViewSource does not update when the source changes

Tags: c#, mvvm, collectionviewsource

I'm using the collection viewsource to filter, group and sort my items but I when I remove or add a component in the source the view doesn't update.

The source:

```
public ObservableCollection<Component> Components
{
    get
    {
        return mComponents;
    }
}
```

The CollectionViewSource:

```
this.ComponentCollection = new CollectionViewSource();
this.ComponentCollection.Source = this.Components;
this.ComponentCollection.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
this.ComponentCollection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Template.ComponentType"));
this.ComponentCollection.SortDescriptions.Clear();
this.ComponentCollection.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Name", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
this.ComponentCollection.Filter += this.Filter;
```

The only way to add or remove the component from the view is to reapply the source:

```
this.ComponentCollection.Source = this.Components;
this.ComponentCollection.View.Refresh();
```

This is the way i use the CollectionViewSource:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ComponentTemplateCollection.View.Groups}"
```

I have no problems with filtering the collection, this works just fine but when it comes to deleting or adding something from my components `this.Components.Remove(x)` it does nothing.

Comment: if the answer helped you, please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently somehow mComponents was overwritten which was the problem for the collection view source. Raising the propertychanged however did nothing. I also needed to call the add and remove in the dispatcher.